# What special character is this space like thousand separator?

Tags: r, excel, character-encoding, special-characters

Sometimes, in a Excel file, I find thousand separators. It is exactly like a space, but it is not. Why, because when you want to replace it, you can't type space. In stead, if you copy paste this "space", the thousand separator inside a figure, then you can replace them.

Since always, I do this, and I still don't know what is this mysterious space like thousand separator.

Now I have a problem because I have to do in R, and copy paste no more works. I think that maybe like the case with €.

When I do : `gsub("€","",Price)`, the euro symbol won't be replaced.

Could you please help ? Thank you

Comment: Fix the tags in your question.

Comment: hi @trojanfoe, do you mean "add more relevant tags" ? I will add "r", and I don't see any other tags. Do you have any suggestions ? Thank you

Comment: Excel is one you mention.

Comment: "character-encoding" ?

Answer (score 3):

That would be [U+2009, "thin space".](https://www.google.nl/search?client=opera&q=unicode+space+characters&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=thousands+separator+space+unicode)

Comment: Thank for your answer, it could've been this one. but it is not. And, I found this site (http://www.fileformat.info/) and I searched for "Space" and I found other space like characters. And it is this one : http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Comment: That;s a regular-width space, not particularly thin. But if it works for you,go ahead.

Comment: It is a 'NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+00A0). and the normal one is 'SPACE' (U+0020). And there are a lot other SPACES... and just with your eyes, it is definitly impossible to say ! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple characters that look like a space character. Because they look similar, it is good to refer to them using the Unicode code.

- U+0020   : this is the normal space character you get when pressing the spacebar on the keyboard
- U+00A0   No-Break Space: this space character is meant to prevent breaking into a new line when word wrapping. In HTML, it is equivalent to `&nbsp;`
- U+2007   Figure Space: this space character is meant to be as wide as a numerical digit, and it prevents line breaking.
- U+2009   Thin Space: this space character is meant to be slightly less wide than a normal space character
- U+202F   Narrow No-Break Space: similar to U+00A0, but narrower in width

There may be others I'm missing.